# Pivot every n number of records

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot-table

I have a table like this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| PI  | VS  | S | HID | DESC          | MS   | QT    |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | 2013 |       |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JAN  | 3677  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | FEB  | 4187  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | MAR  | 3344  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | APR  | 4001  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | MAY  | 4966  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JUN  | 1079  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JUL  | 452   |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | AUG  | 2224  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | SEP  | 45478 |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | OCT  | 2104  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | NOV  | 122   |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | DEC  | 110   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | 2013 |       |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JAN  | 3377  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | FEB  | 4187  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | MAR  | 3344  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | APR  | 4001  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | MAY  | 4966  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JUN  | 1076  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | JUL  | 452   |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | AUG  | 2224  |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | SEP  | 45478 |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | OCT  | 21554 |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | NOV  | 122   |
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1 | DEC  | 110   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to extract the first line and then concatenate the next 12 as fields, using their content as column name.

Something like:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PI  | VS  | S | HID | DESC           | YEAR | JAN  | FEB  | MAR  | APR  | MAY  | JUN  | JUL | AUG  |  SEP  | OCT   | NOV | DEC |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1  | 2013 | 3677 | 4187 | 3344 | 4001 | 4966 | 1079 | 452 | 2224 | 45478 | 2104  | 122 | 110 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 195 | 152 | 0 | 554 | Description 1  | 2013 | 3377 | 4187 | 3344 | 4001 | 4966 | 1076 | 452 | 2224 | 45478 | 21554 | 122 | 110 |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Is something like that even possible?

I've read about pivot tables, which seem to be similar to what I want to do, but I didn't find any example that behaves like that.

How can I do it?

---

What I tried:

```
WITH pivot_data AS (
  SELECT PI, VS, S, HID, DESC, MS, QT VOLUME
  FROM MONTHLY_RATES
)
SELECT *
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (
  sum(VOLUME)
  FOR MS
  IN  (
    'JAN',
    'FEB',
    'MAR',
    'APR',
    'MAY',
    'JUN',
    'JUL',
    'AUG',
    'SEP',
    'OCT',
    'NOV',
    'DEC'
  )
);
```

It works but does omit the year (which I need to preserve), and it ***sums*** up the values for each month in case of duplicate values, which is not what I want.

**UPDATE**

`MONTHLY_RATES` table:

```
CREATE TABLE MONTHLY_RATES (
  PI   VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
  VS   VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),  
  S    VARCHAR2(2 CHAR),  
  HID  VARCHAR2(3 CHAR),  
  "DESC" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR),  
  MS   VARCHAR2(4 CHAR),  
  QT   NUMBER(10,0)
);

INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', '2013', null);
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JAN', '3677');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'FEB', '4187');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'MAR', '3344');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'APR', '4001');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'MAY', '4966');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JUN', '1079');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JUL', '452');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'AUG', '2224');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'SEP', '45478');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'OCT', '2104');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'NOV', '122');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'DEC', '110');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', '2013', null);
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JAN', '3377');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'FEB', '4187');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'MAR', '3344');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'APR', '4001');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'MAY', '4966');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JUN', '1076');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'JUL', '452');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'AUG', '2224');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'SEP', '45478');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'OCT', '21554');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'NOV', '122');
INSERT INTO MONTHLY_RATES VALUES('195', '152', '0', '554', 'Description 1', 'DEC', '110');
```

Comment: Do you really have two the same result set one by one? Were you going to use 2013 and 2014 years instead of 2013 and 2013?

Comment: @zaratustra Unfortunately I don't know that. The table is not filled by me, I just would like to have a more "readable" table, the only thing I know is that I will have 'packs' of 13 rows, the first contains the Year, the other 12 contain months. In fact yes, I can have the same year let's say 30 times (so 30*13 total records, with the same year) with different months values...

Comment: Provide us please either scripts or CTE?

Comment: do you have both numeric and varchar data in your `MS` column?

Comment: @zaratustra what is CTE? And by scripts, do you mean my attempts? I will post them. The MS column is a Varchar that contains a number (the year) in the first of the 13 rows, and a string (3 characters, the month) in the next 12.

Comment: Give us the `montly_rate` table

Comment: How should we differentiate between the 2 sets of records?

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia I know for sure that each set will contain exactly 13 records, one for the year and twelve for the months... That's the only way to differentiate between sets...

Comment: If there is atleast one field to differentiate the 2 sets, then we can use group by to get 2 sets of records. Otherwise, it will be summed up and displayed as a single row, producing exactly the same result what you have already tried.

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia I was hoping there was a way to say "take 13 records and do the pivot - take another 13 records and re-do the pivot - etc" :(

Comment: But how do you determine the thirteen records that are related? There is no inherent order within a table; even if you insert the thirteen at the same time there's no guarantee that they'll be stored or retrieved contiguously. You have to have something that is common to the members of each 'set', and unique to that 'set'.

Comment: I was about to comment the same thing as @AlexPoole. The table has no column that be used to determine how the rows are related (which rows belong to which year.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

```
with t as (
    SELECT PI, MS,VS,S,HID,"DESC", qt
         , case when qt is null and REGEXP_LIKE(ms, '^20') then to_number(ms, '9999') end yr, rownum rn
      FROM MONTHLY_RATES
), t1 as (
    SELECT PI, MS,VS,S,HID,"DESC", qt
         , case when yr is not null then yr 
                    else lag(yr, mod(rn - 1,13)) over(order by rn) 
               end yr
             , 'G' || trunc((rn-1)/13)  grp
      FROM t
)
select distinct f.* from
(SELECT *
  FROM t1
 PIVOT (
        max(qt)
        FOR MS IN  ('JAN','FEB','MAR','APR','MAY ','JUN ','JUL ','AUG ','SEP ','OCT ','NOV ','DEC ')
       ))f

PI  VS  S  HID DESC                    YR GRP      'JAN'      'FEB'      'MAR'      'APR'
--- --- -- --- --------------- ---------- --- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
195 152 0  554 Description 1         2013 G1        3377       4187       3344       4001
195 152 0  554 Description 1         2014 G2        3377       4187       3344       4001
195 152 0  554 Description 1         2013 G0        3677       4187       3344       4001
```

I cut down the result output, so there are not a bunch of months in it.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/65860/2)

Answer (score -2):

Check if this helps you:

**UPDATED FINAL FIDDLE HERE WITH YEAR CONDITION HANDLED**: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3047/2

```
WITH pivot_data AS
(
  SELECT MTEMP1.*, MTEMP2.YEARR FROM
 ( SELECT M1.*, 'G' || TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/13) AS GROUP_ID FROM 
 MYTABLE M1
 ) MTEMP1
 JOIN
  ( SELECT M2.MS YEARR, 'G' || (ROWNUM-1) AS GROUP_ID FROM MYTABLE M2 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (M2.MS,'^20') 

   ) MTEMP2
 ON MTEMP1.GROUP_ID = MTEMP2.GROUP_ID

)

SELECT *
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (
  sum(QT)
  FOR MS
  IN  (     'JAN',        'FEB',        'MAR',        'APR',        'MAY',
            'JUN',        'JUL',        'AUG',        'SEP',        'OCT',
            'NOV',        'DEC'
      )
);
```

---

```
WITH pivot_data AS

(SELECT M1.*, 'G' || TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/13) AS GROUP_ID FROM MYTABLE M1)

SELECT *
FROM pivot_data
PIVOT (
  sum(QT)
  FOR MS
  IN  (     'JAN',        'FEB',        'MAR',        'APR',        'MAY',
            'JUN',        'JUL',        'AUG',        'SEP',        'OCT',
            'NOV',        'DEC'
      )
);
```

*ORIGINAL FIDDLE HERE : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/46263/8
UPDATED FIDDLE HERE to handle more than 26 records** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ecc9/12*

Since you have no column by which you can group the records, but you know for sure that your records have only 13 records each, I am creating a temporary field call `GROUP_ID` which categorises each set of records to separate groups. When you apply pivot for the group, you would get the result what you want.

Comment: This is not what is in the expected output, there is also year, and your answer doesn't provide this information.

Comment: This is just wrong. Look at what your query does when there are more then 26 rows: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ecc9/2 (pay attention to the Jan value on G2 and on G3). And you aren't returning the YEAR column, as per the request.

Comment: @AndriyM: Refer updated fiddle here :<http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ecc9/12> Provides solution when more than 26 rows.

Comment: Actually I forgot to downvote when I commented, but I *am* tempted to do so now, to be honest, because your query is still not returning YEAR and 3 upvotes for half-solution seem too many. Do you think you could review your answer again?

Comment: @AndriyM: Please check now. The year condition is satisfied too...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3047/2  Now, I wish you are tempted to Upvote :D

Comment: @zaratustra: Refer updated answer and fiddle. It handles the year condition. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e3047/2

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia nice, I guess this solution is better than I offered, you need any analytic functions not to use, it's easy to understand.

Comment: The downvote is from me. The reason is that (using `ROWNUM`) you assume that the rows will be returned always in the same order, and that order will be the same as in the OP's sample. This is not guaranteed. So the answer is wrong (based on the question's wrong assumptions but still wrong.) Check this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54ffc/1).

Comment: @ypercube: I know rownum is poor approach. But The OP Mentioned that there is no ordering mechanism at all, so rank over is not possible. Also, the OP mentioned that it will be 13 rows of records in order specified. Without a pattern or order there is not much more than this that can be done!

Comment: @NishanthiGrashia - but 'in order specified' doesn't mean anything. There is no order. I can only guess the OP is assuming an inherent order based on how/when the records were inserted, but that would be a false and unsafe premise. Using `rownum` is also based on the same premise. As ypercube said, that's the question's fault and the data model is broken; but using `rownum` doesn't fix it.

Comment: @AlexPoole: As you said, this is being answered from the same premise that OP is asking. In the OP's context, assuming that the records will have the desired order inherently, this question is answered. The OP might have to further work on it and ensure that the order is maintained explicitly. I do not think this answer deserves this many downvotes!!